# Python3: Find word in list using while-loop

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, while-loop

A simple question, that I've actually had a hard time finding a solution to, as most suggest using the much easier to work with, for loop.

I have an assignment that tells me explicitly to use the while loop to return either true or false, based on if a string occurs in a list.

My current solution (which works) is as follows:

```
def word_in_list(word, words):
x=0
length = int(len(words)) -1

while words[x] != word and x < length:
    x = x+1

    if words[x] == word:
        print (True)

    elif x == length and words[x] != word:
        print (False)
```

My biggest issue has been limiting the function to the length of the list, otherwise I get an error stating "list index out of range".

However, as this is a rather clunky way of doing something so simple, I'm looking for suggestions on how to streamline it a little - if there's a way that is. And as stated, the for-loop, that you'd normally use, is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed a small error and cleaned up a little, but as a simple exercise requiring the use of `while` the algorithm fundamentally looks fine.

```
def word_in_list(word, words):

    x = 0
    length = len(words) - 1

    while x < length:

        if words[x] == word:
            return True

        elif x == length:
            return False

        x += 1

word_in_list('hello', ['now', 'this', 'hello', 'world'])   # True
word_in_list('hello2', ['now', 'this', 'hello', 'world'])  # False
```

Comment: Using `words[x] != word` in `elif` after `if words[x] == word:` seems redundant.

Comment: Thank you! This do indeed look much better, however it's a small mistake in your example, as you add -1 in two places, which equals -2, missed it as well initially, but now it works great! :)

Answer (score 2):

here is something that runs a bit more efficiently.  Each iteration checks two indices, rather than one.

```
def word_in_list(word, words):
    l, r = 0, len(words) - 1
    while l <= r:
        if words[l] == word or words[r] == word:
            return True
        l += 1
        r -= 1
    return False
```

Hope that helps!